# обращение к div'у

Tags: php, css

файл nav.php

```php
<nav>

  <div id="central_content"></div>

</nav>
```

Страница сайта x.php

```php
<body>

  <?php

    include("nav.php");

  ?>

</body>
```

Я хочу поместить в 'central_content' контент, обращаясь из файла x.php. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

файл nav.php

```
<nav>

  <div id="central_content"><?= $content ?></div>

</nav>
```

Страница сайта x.php

```
<body>

  <?php
    $content = 'что-то';
    include("nav.php");

  ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо.
Правда сначала подумал что не работает - поставил include вперед "$content"